# Error while creating Azure VM with Custom image using PowerShell

Tags: azure, powershell

I am creating an Azure VM using custom Image through PowerShell. The custom image having both OS disk and Data disk configuration. But while executing the code, the VM is deploying successfully but the OS disk and data disk configurations are varying.

How can I write the PowerShell code for creating OS disk and Data disk along with the custom image?

Below is the code:

```
#Define the required Parameters

$resourceGroup = "RG-Test2"
$location = "West US3"
$subnetConfig = "mySubnet"
$vnet = "MYvNET"
$vmName = "MyTestVM"
$galleryname = "mygallery"
$ImageDefinitionName = "windowsimage1"

# Install the AZ modules and Login to Azure 
Install-Module -Name Az -AllowClobber -Scope CurrentUser
Connect-AzAccount

#Get the Image details present in resource group
$imageDefinition = Get-AzGalleryImageDefinition `
   -GalleryName $galleryname `
   -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroup `
   -Name $ImageDefinitionName

# Create user credential object which would be used for Virtual machine
do {
    $cred = Get-Credential -Message "Enter a username and password for VM."
    $password = $cred.GetNetworkCredential().Password
    if ($password.Length -lt 8) {

        Write-Host "Password must be at least 8 characters long. Please try again."

    }
    else {
        # Password meets the minimum length requirement.
        # You can proceed with the credential ($cred) as needed.
        break
       }
} while ($true)

# Create an inbound network security group rule for port 3389
$nsgRuleSSH = New-AzNetworkSecurityRuleConfig `
              -Name myNetworkSecurityGroupRuleSSH  `
              -Protocol Tcp `
              -Direction Inbound `
              -Priority 1000 `
              -SourceAddressPrefix * `
              -SourcePortRange * `
              -DestinationAddressPrefix * `
              -DestinationPortRange 3389 `
              -Access Allow

# Create a network security group
$nsg = New-AzNetworkSecurityGroup `
       -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroup  `
       -Location $location `
       -Name myNetworkSecurityGroup `
       -SecurityRules $nsgRuleSSH

# Create a virtual network card and associate with public IP address and NSG
$nic = New-AzNetworkInterface `
         -Name myNic `
         -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroup `
         -Location $location `
         -SubnetId $vnet.Subnets[0].Id `
         -NetworkSecurityGroupId $nsg.Id

# Create a virtual machine configuration

$vmConfig = New-AzVMConfig `
   -VMName $vmName `
   -VMSize Standard_D2s_v3 | `
   Set-AzVMSecurityProfile -SecurityType "TrustedLaunch" | `
   Set-AzVMOperatingSystem -Windows -ComputerName $vmName -Credential $cred | `
   Set-AzVMSourceImage -Id $imageDefinition.Id | `
   Add-AzVMNetworkInterface -Id $nic.Id

# Create a virtual machine
$vm = New-AzVM `
   -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroup `
   -Location $location `
   -VM $vmConfig

# Check if the VM creation was successful
if ($vm) {

    Write-Host "VM '$($vmName)' has been created successfully."

} else {

    Write-Host "Failed to create the VM."

}
```

Answer (score 0):

> How can I write the PowerShell code for creating OS disk and Data disk along with the custom image?

Here is the updated PowerShell script to create the `OS` disk and `Data` disk from a gallery image.

```
 #Create some variables for the new VM.
    $resourceGroup = "xxxxxxx"
    $location = "West US 2"
    $subnetConfig = "vmsubnet2"
    $vnet = "venkatvnet3"
    $vmName = "TestVM3"
    $galleryname = "samplegallery"
    $ImageDefinitionName = "venkat-linux"
    
    $imageDefinition = Get-AzGalleryImageDefinition `
       -GalleryName $galleryname `
       -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroup `
       -Name $ImageDefinitionName
    
       # Create user credential object which would be used for Virtual machine
    do {
        $cred = Get-Credential -Message "Enter a username and password for VM."
        $password = $cred.GetNetworkCredential().Password
        if ($password.Length -lt 8) {
    
            Write-Host "Password must be at least 8 characters long. Please try again."
    
        }
        else {
           
            break
           }
    } while ($true)
    $subnetConfig = New-AzVirtualNetworkSubnetConfig -Name mySubnet -AddressPrefix 192.168.1.0/24
    $vnet = New-AzVirtualNetwork -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroup -Location $location `
      -Name MYvNET -AddressPrefix 192.168.0.0/16 -Subnet $subnetConfig
    $pip = New-AzPublicIpAddress -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroup -Location $location `
      -Name "mypublicdns$(Get-Random)" -AllocationMethod Static -IdleTimeoutInMinutes 4
    $nsgRuleRDP = New-AzNetworkSecurityRuleConfig -Name myNetworkSecurityGroupRuleRDP  -Protocol Tcp `
      -Direction Inbound -Priority 1000 -SourceAddressPrefix * -SourcePortRange * -DestinationAddressPrefix * `
      -DestinationPortRange 3389 -Access Allow
    $nsg = New-AzNetworkSecurityGroup -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroup -Location $location `
      -Name myNetworkSecurityGroup -SecurityRules $nsgRuleRDP
    $nic = New-AzNetworkInterface -Name $vmName -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroup -Location $location `
      -SubnetId $vnet.Subnets[0].Id -PublicIpAddressId $pip.Id -NetworkSecurityGroupId $nsg.Id  
$vmConfig = New-AzVMConfig -VMName $vmName -VMSize Standard_D2s_v3 | `
   Set-AzVMSecurityProfile -SecurityType "Standard" | `
   Set-AzVMOperatingSystem -Windows -ComputerName $vmName -Credential $cred | `
   Set-AzVMSourceImage -Id $imageDefinition.Id | `
   Add-AzVMNetworkInterface -Id $nic.Id 

#Create a virtual machine
New-AzVM -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroup -Location $location -VM $vmConfig
```

Once the PowerShell code is executed, both the `OS` and `data disks`  with same size are created from a gallery image.

[image]

Below are the `OS` and `Data` disks for my gallery image.

[image]

Comment: Hi Venkat, thanks for the solution. But my customer is asking to add code for OS disk as well as data disk separately because they are using custom image which is having both OS disk as well as data disk configuration. But while deploying the disk properties are changing. So they have asked to keep separate code for OS disk and data disk. Any suggestions for this query.

Comment: If you are creating a VM using a gallery image that has both OS and data disks, it's not possible to separate code for the OS and data disks, as the configuration for both is taken from the gallery image by default.

Comment: Hi Venkat. I tried to run the code which you have mentioned but getting below error:
Long running operation failed with status 'Failed'. Additional Info:'OS Provisioning for VM 'TestVM3' did not finish in the allotted time. However, the VM guest agent was detected
     | running. This suggests the guest OS has not been properly prepared to be used as a VM image (with CreateOption=FromImage). To resolve this issue, either use the VHD as is with
     | CreateOption=Attach or prepare it properly for use as an image:  * Instructions for